# How to create a multi container web application in docker

Tags: django, postgresql, web-applications, docker, logstash

I have already created a web application in django/postgresql. I need to do the further enhancement in docker as django, postgres and logstash in separate containers. How can I create such an application in docker ? How can I access it from web browser?

Answer (score 1):

You need to link your docker containers together. This creates a private connection between containers that is not exposed on the network. Containers will automatically "know" about each other.

The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/) goes through this in detail, but here are the key points.

1. Create a container with a custom name `--name db` for example.
2. You need to create all the "sub" containers first, before you create the master container to which they will be linked.
3. You can link multiple containers together.
4. Linked containers share a private network, and environment variables and `/etc/hosts` files are updated by docker automatically (make sure you read the documentation on this part).

In your scenario - you would create your logstash, postgres container first, then create your web container and link the two together. Once linked, your web container will automatically know how to connect to the database container.

As far as web access is concerned, since there is a private network between the linked containers - you get to choose which container you want to be accessible to the web and how. So normally the application/web container will have two network interfaces - one which is the public one and the other private network that is linked to the other containers.

Comment: Yes of course, why not? Its just a normal database server.

Comment: I can not access postgresql, not even to create a database. Can you please share the run command to run postgresql.

Comment: Please ask a separate question.